# Woher kommt die Redewendung "Der Trend geht zum/zur Zweit..."

Tags: etymology, phrase, compound

Man sieht es ab und zu und nutzt es vielleicht sogar selbst:

- Der Trend geht zum Zweitjob ([faz.net](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/arbeitsmarkt-der-trend-geht-zum-zweitjob-11914500.html))
- Der Trend geht zum Zweitbuch ([taz.de](https://taz.de/Von-Anfang-an-dabei/!124983/))
- Der Trend geht zum Zweitberuf ([sueddeutsche.de](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/muenchen/sport/linksaussen-der-trend-geht-zum-zweitberuf-1.4647998))
- Der Trend geht zur Zweitwährung ([welt.de](https://www.welt.de/print-wams/article114927/Der-Trend-geht-zur-Zweitwaehrung.html))

und beliebig viele mehr, wenn man mal eine Suchmaschine bemüht und nach ["Der Trend geht zum"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=der%20trend%20geh%20zum%20zweit) oder ["Der Trend geht zur"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=der%20trend%20geh%20zur%20zweit&t=hj&ia=news) sucht.

Im persönlichen Umfeld kenne ich es eher scherzhaft, wenn zum Beispiel ein Kollege sich noch einen Grill kauft, sagt ein Freund: "Der Trend geht zum Zweitgrill".

Gibt es für diese Redewendung (ist es überhaupt eine Redewendung?) einen ermittelbaren Ursprung?

**Update:**

Die beste Antwort ist bisher [die von Ralf](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58781/1820), zu welcher ich noch folgende Theorie ergänzen möchte:
Ausgerechnet bei [Kamelopedia](http://kamelopedia.net/wiki/Zweitbuch) wird [hominem unius libri timeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_unius_libri) erwähnt: "Ich fürchte den Mann eines Buches", wobei evtl. die Bibel das "Erstbuch" ist.

> The phrase was in origin a dismissal of eclecticism, i.e. the "fear" is of the formidable intellectual opponent who has dedicated himself to and become a master in a single chosen discipline; however, the phrase today most often refers to the interpretation of expressing "fear" of the opinions of the illiterate man who has "only read a single book". The phrase was used by Methodist founder John Wesley, referring to himself, with "one book" taken to mean the Bible.

Ist immer noch weit hergeholt, dient aber vielleicht als Ausgangspunkt für weitere Recherche.

Comment: _Trend_ ist ein Wort das im modernen Deutsch dem Englischen entlehnt wurde. Nach einem etymologischen Ursprung zu fragen macht in diesem Fall m.E. nicht wirklich Sinn.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich frage nicht nach dem Ursprung von "Trend", sondern dem Ursprung der Redewendung/Phrase/Konstruktion

Comment: Na ja, das habe ich schon verstanden. Aber da _Trend_ ein neudeutsches Lehnwort ist, kann auch die Phrase wohl kaum einen etymologischen Ursprung im herkömmlichen Sinne haben (s.a. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologie).

Comment: Ich kenne das seit einigen Jahrzehnten unter "Der Trend geht zum Zweitbuch.", wohl mit der Intention, sich über nicht-lesende Personen lustig zu machen. Für mich die älteste Variante. Ob es bei der Recherche hilft?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Du meinst, der (das?) Tag wäre „etymology“ wäre schlecht gewählt?

Comment: @CarstenS Ja. Etymologie ist die Wissenschaft der _sprachgeschichtlichen Entwicklung von Wörtern_  (oder meinetwegen auch Phrasen). In diesem Fall kann man aber nicht von einer sprachgeschichtlichen Entwicklung sprechen, oder?

Comment: Trend gibt es schon lange. Als statistischer Begriff begegnet er einem zu jeder Wahl (Bu.-Tag, Landtag, Europawahl, ...) aber auch bei Arbeitslosenstatistik u.dgl. Nicht zu vergessen die unzähligen Modetrends. Und meist stellt sich die Frage, wohin der Trend geht. Die Verbindung mit Zweitjob kenne ich noch aus den 90ern im Zusammenhang mit Reportagen über die USA. Später dann hörte ich von den ominösen Zweitbüchern bei der Harald-Schmitt-Show, und habe das auch mal probiert. Aber das heißt nicht, dass Schmitts Schreiber den Spruch erfunden haben. Vielleicht auch aus den USA plagiiert.

Comment: Eine Mögichkeit, wie die Redewendungs ich verbreiten konnte, könnte sein, dass sie zu einem früheren Zeitpunkt in Bezug auf ein sehr allgemeines Thema angewandt wurde. Der "Zweitjob" wäre ein passendes Beispiel, aber auch ein "Zweitwagen" oder eine "Zweitwohnung" wären denkbar und könnten bei der Recherche helfen. (Mir selber ist die Konstruktion u.A. aus den späteren 90ern bekannt als "Der Trend geht zum Zweitcomputer.", was ungefähr zu der Zeit aufkam, als dann viele Haushalte langsam nicht mehr "den Familiencomputer" hatten, sondern nach und nach einen pro Person.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [Beschreibung des Tags Etymologie](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology): "Wortherkunft – The history and languages of origin of words and phrases". Gibt es denn ein passenderes Tag hier?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die Verbreitung der Phrase macht die Onlinerecherche leider sehr schwer. Ich habe durchaus schon (zu) viel Zeit damit verbracht, bevor ich die Frage hier gestellt habe. Mir geht es eher darum, ob es einen konkreten oder präzisen Ursprung gibt, z.B. als Zitat einer bekannten Persönlichkeit.

Comment: Der Hinweis auf das Zweitbuch scheint mir gut zu sein. Da finde ich einen Anstieg um 1980. Für die, die den Charakter einer Redewendung bezweifeln: https://books.google.de/books?id=2gojAQAAIAAJ&q=%22zum+zweitbuch%22+titanic&dq=%22zum+zweitbuch%22+titanic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilmYCwy8zpAhUyyKYKHenUCD8Q6AEIKDAA

Comment: @CarstenS: Dein Zitat sagt aber "Der Trend zum Zweitpunkt wächst", nicht "geht zum", womit Dein Zitat die Redewendungsthese unterminiert, statt sie zu stützen. :)

Comment: @CarstenS Klingt für mich auch nach der bisher heißesten Spur. Zumal es auch den satirischen Charakter hat, den ich der Redewendung oft entnehme. Der Unterschied "zum Zweit... wächst" statt "geht zum Zweit..." ist doch eher marginal. Mal weitersuchen ...

Comment: Gestern ist mir noch eine Idee untergekommen, ausgerechnet von [Kamelopedia](http://kamelopedia.net/wiki/Zweitbuch), was mich zu [hominem unius libri timeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_unius_libri) brachte: "Ich fürchte den Mann eines Buches", wobei evtl. die Bibel das "Erstbuch" ist. Ich ergänze die Frage um die Info.

Comment: Ich denke der Knackpunkt am Zweitbuch ist sicher auch dass Zweitjob, Zweitwagen und Zweitwohnung im Wesentlichen "nur quantitativ" mehr sind - das Zweitbuch aber in der Regel zusätzlich auch qualitativ mehr: das Zweitbuch ist ja in aller Regel nicht das gleiche Buch nochmal, sondern ein anderes, mit anderem Inhalt.

Answer (score 5):

Es ist vielleicht nicht das, was man herkömmlicherweise eine *Redewendung* nennt, eher ein variierbarer *Spruch*, sowas wie '*die Einschläge kommen näher*' oder '*da kommt was auf uns zu*', aber es ist eine beliebte, floskelhafte **Schablone**, die hinsichtlich des Objekts der Zweitanschaffung variabel ist. Manche Redewendungen sind von dieser Art, zum Beispiel auch "*auf ...fang gehen*" (Frauen gehen auf *Männerfang*, kleine Betrüger auf *Dummenfang*, Diebe auf *Beutefang*, Politiker auf *Stimmenfang* oder *Wählerfang* und Kleingewerbetreibende in Touristenhotspots auf *Touristenfang*). Den Ursprung hierfür würde ich stark in der Jagd vermuten, und tatsächlich gibt es etliche aus der Serie auch mit '*...jagd*', und weitere kommen hinzu (*auf Schnäppchenjagd gehen*, analog: *auf Quotenjagd, auf Punktejagd, auf Verbrecherjagd ...* usw. usw. gehen).

"Der Trend geht zum Zweit..." scheint nicht mehr ganz jung, aber auch nicht älter als einige Jahrzehnte zu sein. Der Spruch hört sich für mich werbesprachlich an. Auf Google Ngram Viewer ging es mit "Der Trend geht zu/m/r ..." ziemlich exakt [1960](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Trend%20geht%20zum%2CTrend%20geht%20zur%2CTrend%20geht%20zu&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTrend%20geht%20zum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTrend%20geht%20zur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTrend%20geht%20zu%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CTrend%20geht%20zum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTrend%20geht%20zur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTrend%20geht%20zu%3B%2Cc0) los. Die dort verlinkten frühen Beispiele (unter dem Kurvendiagramm, mit Jahreszahlen, sie lassen sich nach Aufruf nach Datum sortieren) kommen erstaunlicherweise praktisch durchgängig aus dem technischen Bereich. Leider funktioniert diese Suche nicht mit *Zweit...*. Dieses '*Der Trend geht zum Zweit..*' ist bis in die jüngste Zeit sehr produktiv, ständig werden neue Beispiele kombiniert. Dass es die 60er Jahre waren, in denen der Spruch mit dem Trend - vermutlich erst mal ohne "*Zweit...*" - aufkam, könnte zur wirtschaftlichen Situation dieser Zeit passen. An Grundausstattung war dort bei den Haushalten ein gewisser Sättigungsgrad erreicht und die Werbeleute mussten sich etwas einfallen lassen, um die Leute zum weiteren Kaufen zu animieren. Die Argumente waren damals meiner Erinnerung nach sehr platt, da konnte man mit der Berufung auf einen ominösen Trend noch eine gewisse Aufmerksamkeit erzielen.

An Werbeslogans aus dieser Zeit kommt man nicht ohne weiteres heran, um diese einmal systematisch zu durchforsten. Jedenfalls müssen schon längere Zeit **vor** der satirischen "Zweitbuch-"Variante, über die sich alle köstlich amüsierten, viele Zweit-Trends im Deutschen in Umlauf gewesen sein, sonst hätte der Spruch keinen ausreichend hohen Wiedererkennungswert gehabt, um als Witz sofort zu zünden. Es hört sich nach der Erfindung eines Kabarettisten an. Für mich war dazu erst ein Beleg für [1989](https://www.zeit.de/2007/42/Kulturverhalten/seite-3) auffindbar. Damals soll Dieter Hildebrand gesagt haben: »Der Trend zum Zweitbuch ist unübersehbar«.

Comment: Gemessen daran, dass von 1973 zu 1989 der "habe nichts gelesen"-Wert von 43% auf 31% gesunken ist, würde ich den Satz von Hildebrand auf 1989 verorten.

Comment: @Shegit Brahm: Stimmt, danke. Ich hatte mir nicht den Kontext und vor allem nicht den Zeitpunkt der Veröffentlichung klar gemacht. Ich dachte, der Artikel sei von vielleicht 1990, dann wäre mit '_damals_' der weiter zurückliegende Zeitpunkt gemeint gewesen. Aber selbst dann hätte der Autor in der gegebenen Zeit-Konstellation für 1973 das Plusquamperfekt nehmen müssen. Ich hätte nur wenige Zeilen weiter zu lesen brauchen, dann hätte mir klar werden müssen, dass dieser Text aus einer späteren Zeit - es war 2007 - stammt..

Answer (score 3):

Zunächst sei einmal gesagt, dass der erste Teil des gesuchten Ausdrucks "der Trend geht zum Zweit-" aus dem Englischen entlehnt zu sein scheint. Der entsprechende Ausdruck "the trend goes to/towards" tauchte laut [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trend%20goes%20to%2Ctrend%20goes%20towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrend%20goes%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrend%20goes%20towards%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctrend%20goes%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrend%20goes%20towards%3B%2Cc0) in den 1940ern auf und erfreut sich seitdem einiger Beliebtheit. Es ist also kein Wunder, dass der Ausdruck, wie @RalfJoerres bereits schrieb, in den 1960ern in (West-)Deutschland Einzug fand. Man bedenke hierbei den amerikanischen kulturellen Einfluss, die übernahme anderer Wörter und die Menge an Schülern, die diese Sprache neu erlernten.

Den Ursprung der hinzugefügten Silbe "Zweit-" zu finden ist dagegen schwieriger. Vielleicht sogar unmöglich. Erste Quellen, zumindest für die Verwendung des Zweitbuchs, lassen sich jedoch bereits für 1977 belegen. So schrieb das [Börsenblatt für den deutschen Buchhandel](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=_j02AQAAIAAJ&dq=der%20trend%20zum%20zweitbuch&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=trend%20zum%20zweitbuch) in diesem Jahr

> Es ist zu erwarten, daß dieser nunmehr authentisch festgestellte Trend zum Zweit-Buch auch die Produktion der Verlage

bzw. Heike Doutiné / Andreas F. Achenbach in [Iß ein Buch](https://books.google.de/books?id=bvQ2AAAAIAAJ&q=der%20trend%20zum%20zweitbuch&dq=der%20trend%20zum%20zweitbuch&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3tPWFidbpAhUltYsKHdajAI84FBDoAQg8MAM) 1977

> Der Trend heißt: Vorwärts zum Zweitbuch

Auch im Jahr 1978 fand der Ausdruck [Einzug in das Börsenblatt](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=GDk2AQAAIAAJ&dq=zweitbuch&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=zweitbuch%20).

Dass der Ausdruck sich Verfangen hat zeigt die Verwendung im [Spiegel von 1981](https://books.google.de/books?id=ACRRAAAAYAAJ&q=der+trend+zum+zweitbuch&dq=der+trend+zum+zweitbuch&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3tPWFidbpAhUltYsKHdajAI84FBDoAQguMAE)

> Stellen Sie das Überblättern ein! Hier wird gelesen! Nämlich: Der Trend zum Zweitbuch hält an.

Die Aussage, dass der Ausdruck *Zweitbuch* auf ein weiteres Buch neben der Bibel anspielt halte ich für nicht abwegig. Offziell ist in Deutschland zwar das "Zweitbuch" eine Abschrift des [Geburtenbuchs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geburtenbuch), aber ein Bezug darauf ergibt im Kontext keinen Sinn. Anspielungen darauf aus der Zeit um 1977 fand ich zwar keine, aber in *neuerer* Zeit findet man Sätze wie

> eines jeden deutschen Hauswesens (sozusagen als Zweitbuch neben der Bibel) gehöre

[Nachtgedanken: oder Der Garten als realisierte Utopie - Hans Hermann Wöbse](https://books.google.de/books?id=TbIpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=zweitbuch+bibel&source=bl&ots=oNqpKSiLgO&sig=ACfU3U0QvvXKfWOBq2xCGqAwujrU7B-3Mg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi71InfkNbpAhXjz4UKHXbwB5EQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=zweitbuch%20bibel&f=false)

oder

> der Trend zum christlichen Zweitbuch nach der Bibel sollte zunehmend nicht an uns vorübergehen

[Lebendiger Glaube: Liedpredigten zu neuen und alten Liedern - Friedrich Wintzer (1997)](https://books.google.de/books?id=cdMUDqrq_tkC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=zweitbuch&source=bl&ots=Bt22qYKx7N&sig=ACfU3U292es_HLIeMwQ_rsApsj5xm6pJyQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW5LTPvdbpAhWKyaQKHQPICRcQ6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=zweitbuch&f=false)

Wer den Ausdruck *Zweitbuch* erfand ist hier mit vertretbarem Aufwand nicht endgültig zu klären. Für die Verbreitung scheinen allerdings Kaberettisten gesorgt zu haben, wie folgendens Zitat aus [Buchkulter vom Verein Buchkultur (1990)](https://books.google.de/books?id=tFRXAAAAYAAJ&q=%22der%20trend%20zum%20zweitbuch%22&dq=%22der%20trend%20zum%20zweitbuch%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU_prUlNbpAhUlxosKHbSwAnwQ6AEIZjAJ) zeigt

> Gerade in einem Land wie Österreich, wo der Trend zum Zweitbuch leider keine Erfindung naseweiser Kabarettisten ist.

Anscheinend eine Anspielung auf Auftritte von [Dieter Hildebrand in Österreich](https://www.zeit.de/2007/42/Kulturverhalten/seite-3), siehe Antwort von @RalfJoerres. Hierzu auch folgendes Hildebrandt-Zitat:

> Und das ist gut. Denn auf der Frankfurter Buchmesse gab es in diesem Jahre 200 000 Neuerscheinungen. 200 000! Aber das beweist, dass es im deutschen Volke einen deutlichen Hang zum Zweitbuch git!

[Was aber bleibt: Texte aus fünf Jahrzehnten - Dieter Hildebrandt](https://books.google.de/books?id=i4OmDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT419&dq=Dieter%20Hildebrandt%20%22zweitbuch%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA6-_QmNbpAhWOyaQKHRqUBToQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Dieter%20Hildebrandt%20%22zweitbuch%22&f=false)

---

Um zum Ende zu kommen denke ich, dass Abwandlungen des "Der Trend geht zum Zweit-" auf dem Ausdruck Zweitbuch beruhen, der von einem oder mehreren Kabarettisten durch ihre Auftritte bekannt geworden ist. Ob es sich "nur" um Dieter Hildebrand oder noch andere handelt ist hier nicht zu beantworten. Er könnte den Ausdruck jedenfalls populär gemacht zu haben. Wer ihn erfunden hat - wer weiß. Der Ausdruck an sich besteht jedenfalls bereits seit mindestens 1977.

**EDIT:**

Folgendes Zitat aus [Deutsche Bauzeitung: Fachzeitschrift für Architektur und Bautechnik, Band 110](https://books.google.de/books?id=vLNUAAAAMAAJ&q=%22zweit-buch%22&dq=%22zweit-buch%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCuLCB09bpAhXymIsKHQphBnA4ChDoAQhLMAU) von 1976 lässt den Ursprung tatsächlich im Buchhandel / im Umfeld einer Buchmesse vermuten:

> Wenn nach der letzten Buchmesse gewitzelt wurde, daß ein Verbrauchertrend zum Zweit-Buch festzustellen sei.

Das Wort Zweit-Buch im "Nicht-Geburtsbuch-Sinn" tauchte allerdings schon 1968 im Satire-Magazin [Eulenspiegel](https://books.google.de/books?id=ae08AQAAIAAJ&q=%22zweit-buch%22&dq=%22zweit-buch%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCuLCB09bpAhXymIsKHQphBnA4ChDoAQhrMAk) auf:

> Achtung, Buchbesitzer! Sie haben schon eins, sagen Sie? Wissen Sie nicht, daß es in unserer Zeit vorteilhaft und modern ist ein Zweit-Buch zu erwerben?

Comment: Super recherchiert, danke! Mir war der englische Ausdruck gar nicht geläufig. Wenn man Ngram bemüht, scheint es auch so, dass die Verwendung im Deutschen stärker steigt. Ein einzelner Ursprung scheint unrealistisch zu sein, aber ich denke, wir sind der Sache ein ganzes Stück näher gekommen, wenn es überhaupt noch näher geht.

Comment: Gefällt mir. Sehr!

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann hier keine spezielle Redewendung erkennen.

Trend ist eine Richtungsangabe, und das Ziel ist sinnvollerweise anzugeben, wenn es über ein bloßer *oben*/*unten* hinausgeht. (Bevor *Trend* im Trend lag, hätte man vielleicht *Tendenz* verwendet.)

Wenn der Trend darin besteht, dass es eben nicht nur ein einzelnes Objekt ist, wie bei *der Trend geht zum Eigenheim*, dann liegt *der Trend geht zum/zur Zweit-* sprachlich so nahe, dass das jede/r auch ohne historische Vorlage bilden würde.

Ein Beitrag zur Verbreitung dürfte das elegante Wortbildungsmuster *Zweit-* geleistet haben, das im Englischen durch das vorgestellte Adjektiv *second* ersetzt werden muss. Der früheste Treffer, den ich bei DWDS gefunden habe, ist *Zweitwagen*:

> Eva und das Auto, Hamburg: BP Benzin und Petroleum Aktiengesellschaft Verl. 1966, S. 6
>
> Es gibt eine vorzügliche Lösung, die derartigen Problemen auf das zuverlässigste und beste vorbeugt: den Zweitwagen, den Extrawagen für die Dame.

Comment: Es tut mir leid, aber Dein erster Satz sagt mir, dass Du nicht hättest antworten sollen.

Comment: Der Trend geht zur Zweitantwort^^